# Read command-line parameters to .bat from file

Tags: batch-file, dos

I have a build.bat file which uses %1 internally... so you might call:

> build 1.23

I wanted it to read the parameter from a separate file, so I tried putting "1.23" in version.txt and doing:

> build < version.txt

But it doesn't work. Isn't this how piping works? Is what I want possible and if so how?

Comment: The way you are doing is that you are piping contents of version.txt to standard input of build command/executable. Is that what you're trying to do? This is NOT  same as passing arguments to command, as your program would have to handle it differently.

Comment: @mr.b yes I want content of version.txt passed as command-line parameter, so build doesn't have to change at all. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FOR` command in DOS has a form which parses files and assigns the tokens it finds to variables, which can then be used as arguments to other batch files.  Assuming `version.txt` contains the single line "1.23", this batch file will open it, assign 1.23 to the variable, then call your original batch file, passing the variable's value as a command-line argument.

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in (version.txt) do call build.bat %%i
```

If `version.txt` contains more than one line, `build.bat` is called once for each line.  Type `help for` at a DOS prompt to see what other features you might be able to use.

Answer (score -1):

I think it would make more sense if you handle the file processing within the batch file on the off chance that version.txt is not edited correctly.

You should modify your script to parse the file to get the version if the .bat file is executed as:

```
     build FILE version.txt
```

Comment: I don't understand what the second half of your answer means

Comment: I mean just the change the start of your .bat file that handle the command line arguments to parse the file version.txt if the .bat script is executed like that.  In my opinion, that would get what you want while maintaining clarity